# ios charts don't register touching and never show markers

Tags: ios, swift, charts, tableview

I have a list of charts in a tableview (each cell is a chart view) and I'm trying to add a custom marker (tried with balloonmarker) so that when the user taps on one of the data points a marker should pop up and show additional info about this point. My tableview cell is ChartViewDelegate and I implemented chartValueSelected method in it so that this thing could work but the problem is that most of the taps don't register at all. Basically the app doesn't recognize which view the user is tapping on, so I have to scroll up and down until it recognizes that I'm selecting a specific view. These cells take up the whole screen so I can't understand why it has such a hard time determining the view I'm tapping.

Comment: Can you show your code of the tableView and cell. Have you set the chart delegate to the cell's class?

Comment: yeap, it's all set. I guess it wouldn't register taps on the chart at all if it wasn't